# 用語 disparity と parallax の違い

Tags: 画像

3次元コンピュータグラフィクス(3D CG)や立体視ステレオパノラマ画像処理などの分野で用いられる単語で、日本語ではどちらも「視差」と訳される "**disparity**" と "**parallax**" ですが、英語表記だと一定の使い分けルールがあるように思います。どのような違いがあるのでしょうか？

- 両眼視差(binocular disparity; parallax)
- 視差マップ(disparity map)
- 運動視差(motion parallax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

映像情報メディア学会による講座「[誰にでもわかる3D 第1回, 基礎1：空間立体視の手がかりとは？](https://www.ite.or.jp/contents/tech_guide/tech_guide201101_201112.pdf)」では、下記のように説明されています。

> 3.2 両眼による空間知覚要因
>   [...] このうち，左右眼から見る方向の差（parallax）と左右眼の網膜像の差（disparity）は，共に（両眼）視差として表現される場合が多い．[...]

- parallax ＝ 被写体に対する**観測点**(カメラやヒトの眼)位置・方向の違い
- disparity ＝ 上記系により観測された**画像データ**の違い